# Evenly create gaps between objects?

Tags: objects

I've got a bunch of randomly-sized pillars and they are all connected. I want to create an even gap between all the pillars, almost like a city. I can't find a way to accomplish this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Scale center points

You can **manipulate the center points** of the objects by enabling the little icon with the double arrows next to the pivot center select.

[image]

By setting the 3D cursor as pivot you'll be able to ***Scale*** not the object, but only it's center point location on the needed axis (X firts and then Y in the example shown below):

[image]

Comment: Man, just beat me to it. Great gif, tho!